# How to Make Multi Select Code Block Embeds In Html

Tags: html, css, codeblocks

I am trying to make something like this.
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwRge.png)

But I can't seem to find any tutorials or code examples on making code blocks with multi selectable languages in html/css.

I don't know much CSS, and only need this for the landing page of my API.

Does anyone have any examples or videos on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have code for this as I stated if you read the question

Comment: You have an image of text.  Please post the text here.  It is assumed here, that you have had a go and that you are posting your failed attempts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
curl --request POST \
--data '{&quot;perosnalizations&quot;: {{&quot;email&quot;:test@example.com&quot;
```

Hopefully this will get you started.

```
curl --request POST \
--data '{&quot;perosnalizations&quot;: {{&quot;email&quot;:test@example.com&quot;
```

the easy way to do this is by using an escaper like this one https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html#before-output